# Fetch Google Contacts for iOS application if User already logged in

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api

In my application we kept option to login through gmail/facebook. I have requirement to get gmail contacts. I have seen GData library in which "GDataServiceGoogleContact" object is creating with username and password.

My requirement is if i already login with gmail(using google plus SDK),how to fetch contacts by url "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/default/full". or is there any option using iOS google plus  SDK.

Comment: Hi did you find any resolution to this